# issue with my .htaccess file preventing 404 redirect

Tags: file, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have in my .htaccess file the following,

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
# Redirect Writeback
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /user.php?u=$1 [L]
# Redirect Rule
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?u=([^&\ ]+)($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

As you can see I am trying to redirect if the page is not found, but mod_rewrite is preventing it from working, so I put it in multiple places to see if it made a difference, but it doesnt. how can I fix the 404 redirect and still have the other rewriteruile working as it should? To clearify, if you go to `jnetscripts.com/multimedia` it's actually pointing to file `jnetscripts.com/user?u=multime`.

UPDATE:
Ok I fixed this issue inside my user.php file using the following code, hope this helps anyone with same issue I had.

```
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
if ($numrows < 1) {
  header("location: /notfound.php");
}
```

Comment: @jacouh The title isn't for the status of a question, so I rollbacked it. For OP: I believe you can answer your own question at any time, so I would recommend editing out your update and putting it in an answer instead. You can accept that answer after some time.

Comment: @Sumurai8, OK. This is Alright.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are internally rewriting to a page `user.php` that actually exists, the ErrorDocument will not get triggered.

You can use the technique you are doing by testing if that thing exists in your database and redirect to the 404 page with:

```
header( "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporary" );
header( "Location: /404.php" );
exit();
```

This will redirect to the 404 page, and `/404.php` will be displayed in the url bar.

---

An other way of handling is, by detecting if that thing exists in the database and include the 404 page. If you have a 404-header in your `404.php`, then the header is not required. The client will see `example.com/blah` in the url bar, which will be internally rewritten to `user.php?u=blah`.

```
header( "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" );
require_once( "path/to/404.php" );
exit();
```